# find all subcartesian products of $S_4$ and $D_{12}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, permutations

The following exercise is from [Cameron, *Permutation Groups*]:

> Find all permutation groups of degree 10 which have orbits of length 4 and 6 and act on these orbits as the symmetric group $S_4$ and the dihedral group $D_{12}$ respectively, where $S_4$ acts in the natural way and $D_{12}$  acts as on the vertices of a regular hexagon.

I think the problem is asking to find all the subcartesian products of the two groups $S_4$ and $D_{12}$.  Recall that given two groups $G_1 \le S^{\Omega_1}$ and $ G_2 \le S^{\Omega_2}$,  a subcartesian product of these two groups is any subgroup of the cartesian product $G_1 \times G_2$ whose restriction map on $\Omega_i$ is onto $G_i$ for each $i$.

One way to obtain these subgroups is to work with generators of the two groups. We know that $x=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4), y=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ are two elements that generate $G_1=S^{\Omega_1}$ and $r=(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_6),s=(\beta_2,\beta_6)(\beta_3,\beta_5)$ generate $G_2=D_{12} \le S^{\Omega_2}$.  We are looking for all subgroups $H$ of $G_1 \times G_2 = \langle x,y,r,s \rangle$ that satisfy the property that $H^{\Omega_1} \cong S_4$ and $H^{\Omega_2} \cong D_{12}$.

One such subgroup $H$ is of course all of $G_1 \times G_2$ itself, which has 288 elements. We could also consider different combinations of the two generating sets; for example, $H = \langle xr, ys \rangle$ is also a subcartesian product, but it needs to be shown it is a proper subgroup of $G_1 \times G_2$.  Surely any $H$ that answers our question would have at least 24 elements since $|G_1|=24$.  But it's not clear to me how all these subgroups $H$ can be obtained.

Answer (score 2):

Let $K$ be a subdirect product of $G_1 \times G_2$, and let $N_1 = \{g \in G_1 \mid (g,1) \in K \}$ and $N_2 = \{ g \in G_2 \mid (1,g) \in K \}$.

Then $N_1 \unlhd G_1$, $N_2 \unlhd  G_2$, with $G_1/N_1 \cong K/(N_1 \times N_2) \cong G_2/N_2$.

The normal subgroups of $S_4$, are $S_4,A_4,V_4$ and $1$. If $N_1=S_4$, then $N_2=D_{12}$ and $K = S_4 \times D_{12}$.

There is no possible $N_2$ when $N_1=1$.

When $N_1=V_4$, $G_1/N_1 \cong D_6$, so $N_2$ must be the unique normal subgroup of $D_{12}$ of order $2$, giving one possible $K$, with $|K|=48$.

When $N_1=A_4$, $|G_1/N_1|=2$, and there are three possible $N_2$, giving three groups $K$ with $|K|=144$. Two of these are actually isomorphic groups, but they are distinct as permutation groups.

Comment: How can we show that $G_1/N_1 \cong K/(N_1 \times N_2) \cong G_2/N_2$.  Given that $V_4 \times C_2 \le K$, how do we construct the group $K$ of order 48? According to GAP there are 6 groups of order 48.  And similarly, how do we construct the groups $K$ of order 144 given the group $N_1 \times N_2$ of order 72?

Comment: Ok, I can see why $G_1/N_1 \cong K/(N_1 \times N_2) \cong G_2/N2$: since $K$ is a subdirect product, we have that the lattice of subgroups of $G_1 \times G_2$ contains edges $N_1 \times 1 \trianglelefteq G_1 \times 1 \le K, 1 \times N_2 \trianglelefteq 1 \times G_2 \le K$; $N_1 \times 1, 1 \times N_2 \le N_1 \times N_2 \trianglelefteq K$, and we can apply the diamond/isomorphism theorems.  I need to think about the second part of my comment on how to construct all the permutation groups $K$.

Comment: I need to think about this more.  In general, $G_1 \times 1$ need not be contained in $K$.

Comment: The map $\phi: K \rightarrow G_1/N_1$ defined by $\phi(g_1,g_2):=N_1 g_1$ is a surjective homomorphism with kernel $N_1 \times N_2$.  So this proves that the factor groups are isomorphic.